# dyld: force binding of a symbol from a particular library

Tags: macos, openal, dyld

Due to an unfortunate piece of history, OpenAL.framework includes the symbols for ALUT 1.0. I'm working on a project that benefits from ALUT 1.1, so I've compiled ALUT as a framework (from the freealut sources).

Unfortunately, this means there's certain symbols which are defined in both ALUT.framework and OpenAL.framework, and I really need a way to ensure the ALUT ones are picked in preference. I've ordered ALUT before OpenAL on the link command, and hence in the otool output for the final binary, but (due to lazy binding?) the OpenAL symbols are picked in one case. (Actually at application shutdown, the alutExit call goes awry)

I realise this is at odds to the design of dyld, but I'm stuck with the official Apple OpenAL framework. I could hack my ALUT framework to use custom symbol names, but I'm hoping for a neater (if hacky) work-around to force all ALUT symbols to be bound greedily before OpenAL is considered.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but thought I should get this off the 'unanswered' list - we stopped using ALUT in that project.